# Alterar um mesmo arquivo de varias pastas

Tags: python, lista

Pessoal é o seguinte tenho que alterar um arquivo que encontra-se em diversas pastas (Pasta_raiz: H1, H2, H3, N1, N2,N2...)

Fiz um código que pegasse apenas o H1 para testar as alterações, deu certo, mas agora preciso fazer para todos de uma vez, lembrando que dentro de casa pasta existe o arquivo de mesmo nome.

Este é o código para a pasta H1 agora preciso fazer que ele replique de uma vez para todas as pastas.

```
# -------------------------------------
# BIBLIOTECA 
# -------------------------------------

import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from os import walk


#-------------------------------------
#LEITURA NIFTI
#-------------------------------------

img = nib.load('H1/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz')
img.shape
img2 = img.get_fdata()
y = np.ravel(img2)
x = np.unique(y)

#-------------------------------------
#REMOVER LINHAS 
#-------------------------------------

z = np.delete(x, (0, 4, 23, 47, 48, 50, 79, 80, 82), axis=0)

#-------------------------------------
# REMOVE NUMEROS DUPLICADOS
#-------------------------------------

def remove_duplicados(y):
    l = [0]
    for i in y:
        if i not in l:
          l.append(i)
    l.sort()
    return l

y = remove_duplicados(y)
```

Comment: Posso te ajudar, mas antes me informa, você quer alterar todos os arquivos que estão nas pastas ou apenas um específico que também está nas outras pastas?

Comment: opa legal amigo, então apenas o mesmo arquivo que encontra-se em todas as pastas. para facilitar, o nome do arquivo é aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz este arquivo esta em todas as pastas.

Exemplo:

user/H1/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz
user/H2/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz
.
.
.
user/Hn/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz

Comment: Fiz um código que pode te ajudar, só faz um backup antes das suas pastas e arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

Se todas essas pastas(H1,H2,H3,N1,N2,N2...) estão na mesma pasta (Vamos chamar de **ALL**) , você pode extrair as pastas do **ALL** para uma *list* com uma função do *os*:

```
import os

pastas = os.listdir('C:\\CAMINHO\QUALQUER\ALL')
```

E usar loop *for*:

```
for item in pastas:
```

A pasta seria *item*, o caminho do arquivo seria '*item*/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz'. Entâo juntaremos as duas *strings*, *item* + '/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz':

```
img = nib.load(item + '/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz')
```

Ficaria assim:

```
# -------------------------------------
# BIBLIOTECA 
# -------------------------------------

import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from os import walk
import os

# -------------------------------------
# LOOP 
# -------------------------------------

pastas = os.listdir('C:\\CAMINHO\QUALQUER\ALL')

for item in pastas:
    #-------------------------------------
    #LEITURA NIFTI
    #-------------------------------------

    img = nib.load(item + '/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz')
    img.shape
    img2 = img.get_fdata()
    y = np.ravel(img2)
    x = np.unique(y)

    #-------------------------------------
    #REMOVER LINHAS 
    #-------------------------------------

    z = np.delete(x, (0, 4, 23, 47, 48, 50, 79, 80, 82), axis=0)

    #-------------------------------------
    # REMOVE NUMEROS DUPLICADOS
    #-------------------------------------

    def remove_duplicados(y):
        l = [0]
        for i in y:
            if i not in l:
              l.append(i)
        l.sort()
        return l

    y = remove_duplicados(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu código para realizar a leitura, remover as linhas e remover os números duplicados já funciona, basta você iterar sobre as pastas iniciando da pasta raiz.

Antes de tentar o código abaixo, faça um backup das suas pastas.

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import os

path_raiz = 'INSIRA O CAMINHO DA PASTA RAIZ' # Exemplo: 'C://users//fulano//Desktop ...'

# Loop para acessar as pastas que estão na pasta raiz
for pastas in os.listdir(path_raiz):

    # Loop para acessar os arquivos que estão nas pastas
    for arquivos in os.listdir(f'{path_raiz}\\{pastas}'):

        if os.path.basename(arquivos) == 'aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz':

            #-------------------------------------
            #LEITURA NIFTI
            #-------------------------------------

            img = nib.load('H1/aparc.DKTatlas+aseg.nii.gz')
            img.shape
            img2 = img.get_fdata()
            y = np.ravel(img2)
            x = np.unique(y)

            #-------------------------------------
            # REMOVER LINHAS 
            #-------------------------------------

            z = np.delete(x, (0, 4, 23, 47, 48, 50, 79, 80, 82), axis=0)

            #-------------------------------------
            # REMOVE NUMEROS DUPLICADOS
            #-------------------------------------

            def remove_duplicados(y):
                l = [0]
                for i in y:
                    if i not in l:
                        l.append(i)
                l.sort()
                return l

            y = remove_duplicados(y)
```

Por favor, nos informe se a resposta deu certo.